# Replacing <a> tag inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page that loads some content from another domain inside an iframe. I need to replace some content inside this iFrame, specifically the destination for a button. The closest I have come so far is this bit of jQuery code:

```
$("#frameid").contents().find("div").html('My html');
```

The problem is that this works for replacing content between the tags, not the tag itself - which is what I need in order to be able to alter the href property of the a tag.

So the question is: how can I replace a tag (not the content between tags) of some HTML inside an iFrame?

Comment: You don't have access to the content in an iFrame when it's not on the same domain, as the same origin policy prohibits it.

Comment: could you try to change the html of the parent node which contains the <a> tag?

Comment: Exactly, is the page you want to modify on the same domain?

Comment: @Drewness The page is on a different domain. Is there no way to modify the content in the browser, after it's loaded? I have tried the solutions suggested below, and they work when the code is all on the same page, but not on an iFrame, even if everything is local.

Comment: @FernandoGarridoVaz - That is correct, it falls under the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for .replaceWith() http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

```
$("#frameid").contents().find("div").replaceWith('<a>New Element</a>');
```

If it is just attributes, use .attr() http://api.jquery.com/attr/